# Оптимизация рендеринга HTML

Tags: php

Есть три ссылки на сортировки (по статусу, эл. адресу, имени), по умолчанию - все по возрастанию. Как эффективно сделать так, что когда ты находишься на какой-нибудь страничке с выбранной сортировкой (будь то `/sort/status_desc/` или `/sort/status_asc/)`, соответствующая кнопка изменяла свою ссылку на *противоположную*, т.е на сортировку убыванием?

Нахожусь на `/sort/status_desc/` - ссылка меняется на `/sort/status_asc/`.

Вот, что я сделал, но я считаю этот код неэффективным, потому что занимает слишком много места, если прикрутить еще к каждой ссылке `<div>` с классами:

```
Сортировать по:
<?php if($sort == 'status_asc'): ?>
    <a href="/sort/status_desc/">Статусу</a>
    <a href="/sort/email_asc/">Эл. Почте</a>
    <a href="/sort/name_asc/">Имени</a>
<?php endif;?>

<?php if($sort == 'email_asc'): ?>
    <a href="/sort/status_asc/">Статусу</a>
    <a href="/sort/email_desc/">Статусу</a>
    <a href="/sort/name_asc/">Имени</a>
<?php endif;?>

<?php if($sort == 'name_asc'): ?>
    <a href="/sort/status_asc/">Статусу</a>
    <a href="/sort/email_asc/">Эл. Почте</a>
    <a href="/sort/name_desc/">Статусу</a>
<?php endif;?>

// еще 3 проверки на сортировки убыванием (sort_desc)

<?php if(!isset($sort)): ?>
    <a href="/sort/status_asc/">Статусу</a>
    <a href="/sort/email_asc/">Эл. Почте</a>
    <a href="/sort/name_asc/">Имени</a>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Эмм, оптимизация рендеринга? 
Страницы тормозят от одного и это JS. от пхп тормоза только на серваке:)

А так очень не эффективный код слижком много ?php...

Вообще сделайте ген из массива чтоли...

```
например

$array = array(
     array('url'=>'?home=ffff', 'title'=>4444),
     array('url'=>'?sss=eee', 'title'=>5657, 'header'=>ttt)

)


foreach($array as $v){
      .........
}
```